# Fetch function in React Native with mobx-react-lite and React hooks

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I'm newbie in mobx-react and i need to write fetch function that get data from API and after renders it to FlatList. I have already created fetch function, set initial state with useContext hook and wrapped my app by observer mobx class. But now i need to implement of getting the data from the server. Can you tell me please which will be the best way to do it?

```
import { createContext } from 'react'
import { action, decorate, observable, computed, runInAction } from 'mobx'
import fetchData from '../utils/fetchData'
import mapObjects from '../utils/mapObjects'

class DataStore {
  data = null
  error = false
  loading = true

  get getData(){
    return this.data
  }

  get getError(){
    return this.error
  }

  get getLoading(){
    return this.loading
  }

  async fetchData(url) {
  this.data = null
  this.error = false
  this.loading = true
    try {
      console.log('TRY')
      const response = await fetch(url)
      const jsonResponse = await response.json()
      const obj = await mapObjects(jsonResponse)
      runInAction(() => {
        console.log('WRITE!!!')
        this.loading = false
        this.data = obj
      })
    } catch (err) {
      runInAction(() => {
        console.log(err)
        this.loading = false
        this.error = err
      })
    }
  }
}

decorate(DataStore, {
  data: observable,
  error: observable,
  loading: observable,
  fetchData: action
})

export default createContext(new DataStore())
```

My component:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Platform, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import DataStore from '../mobx/DataStore'
import { autorun } from 'mobx'
import { ChartsHeader, CryptoItem, IconsHeader, ProjectStatusBar } from '../components'
import { useFetch } from '../hooks/useFetch'
import { WP, HP } from '../constants'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
})
const ChartsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { container } = styles
  const store = useContext(DataStore)
  const url = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker'

  console.log('store', store)
  useEffect(() => {
    store.fetchData(url)
  }, [])
  //*Call custom hook and data distruction
  //const { data, error, loading } = useFetch(url)

  //*Change percent amount color depends on the amount
  const percentColorHandler = number => {
    return number >= 0 ? true : false
  }

  return (
    <View style={container}>
      {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <ProjectStatusBar />}
      <IconsHeader
        dataError={store.error}
        header="Charts"
        leftIconName="ios-arrow-back"
        leftIconPress={() => navigation.navigate('Welcome')}
      />
      <ChartsHeader />
      <ActivityIndicator animating={store.loading} color="#068485" style={{ top: HP('30%') }} size="small" />
      <FlatList
        data={store.data}
        keyExtractor={item => item.key}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <CryptoItem
            name={item.key}
            highBid={item.highestBid}
            lastBid={item.last}
            percent={item.percentChange}
            percentColor={percentColorHandler(item.percentChange)}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export { ChartsScreen }
```

Comment: Please provide the complete source of your component, as it's tricky to understand what's going on from this excerpt.

Comment: Please can you check, i change my code. At the moment its working, but with very strange behavior: useEffect -> start loading data -> the data have to be render in the component, but it is not happenning, only when i change the navigation stack the data is came. It means i push the button to change the screen and after the data is rendering on a previous screen. I thin the problem in change state in MobX. Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

For everybody who is still looking for the approach for the fetch function in React with MobX. I checked a lot of information, but could not find a good decision. But in the end I created mine. Maybe it will help for somebody: 
MobX store:

```
import { action, observable, runInAction } from 'mobx'

class DataStore {
  @observable data = null
  @observable error = false
  @observable fetchInterval = null
  @observable loading = false

  //*Make request to API
  @action.bound
  fetchInitData() {
    const response = fetch('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker')
    return response
  }

  //*Parse data from API
  @action.bound
  jsonData(data) {
    const res = data.json()
    return res
  }

  //*Get objects key and push it to every object
  @action.bound
  mapObjects(obj) {
    const res = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
      let newData = obj[key]
      newData.key = key
      return newData
    })
    return res
  }

  //*Main bound function that wrap all fetch flow function
  @action.bound
  async fetchData() {
    try {
      runInAction(() => {
        this.error = false
        this.loading = true
      })
      const response = await this.fetchInitData()
      const json = await this.jsonData(response)
      const map = await this.mapObjects(json)
      const run = await runInAction(() => {
        this.loading = false
        this.data = map
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      runInAction(() => {
        this.loading = false
        this.error = err
      })
    }
  }

  //*Call reset of MobX state
  @action.bound
  resetState() {
    runInAction(() => {
      this.data = null
      this.fetchInterval = null
      this.error = false
      this.loading = true
    })
  }

  //*Call main fetch function with repeat every 5 seconds
  //*when the component is mounting
  @action.bound
  initInterval() {
    if (!this.fetchInterval) {
      this.fetchData()
      this.fetchInterval = setInterval(() => this.fetchData(), 5000)
    }
  }

  //*Call reset time interval & state
  //*when the component is unmounting
  @action.bound
  resetInterval() {
    if (this.fetchInterval) {
      clearTimeout(this.fetchInterval)
      this.resetState()
    }
  }
}

const store = new DataStore()
export default store
```